# Initializing a javascript object containing an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have the following C++ struct which I want to create as faithfully as possible in Javascript:

```
struct Vertex
{
   float coords[4];
   float colors[4];
};
```

So I did the following:

```
function Vertex(coords, colors)
{
   this.coords = [];
   this.colors = [];
}
```

Now, the following works to create a Vertex instance:

```
var oneVertex = new Vertex();
oneVertex.coords = [20.0, 20.0, 0.0, 1.0];
oneVertex.colors = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0];
```

but the following (slicker?) doesn't:

```
var oneVertex = new Vertex([20.0, 20.0, 0.0, 1.0], 
                            [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]);
```

Why? I am new to Javascript and what little I have read suggests it should be ok. Obviously not. It would be helpful to understand what I am missing. Thanks.

Comment: you are passing the arrays to the function, but you are setting the coords and colors to empty and not using the data you pass in

Comment: There's a strong distinction between function parameters and object properties. Learning language basics is always a good start.

Answer (score 5):

you need to use the arguments passed in to the function for it to work, as:

```
function Vertex(coords, colors)
{
   this.coords = coords || [];
   this.colors = colors || [];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're constructor should initialize the properties:

```
function Vertex(coords, colors)
{
   this.coords = coords;
   this.colors = colors;
}

var oneVertex = new Vertex([20.0, 20.0, 0.0, 1.0], 
                            [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]);
```